# interchange limits (not a sequence of function)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

I am aware of a theorem in analysis regarding the result that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow x} \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(t) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow t} f_n(t).$$

My question is about interchanging two limit operators as well but it does not involve a sequence of functions. Here goes:

I have a continuous function $C(uw_1,uw_2)$. One research paper I'm reading makes use of the interchange of the derivative and the limit. (I am aware that there is a theorem for switching derivatives and limits which is an analogue to the above but I do recognize that the derivative can be expressed as a limit.)

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} \lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \frac{C(uw_1,uw_2)}{u} = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \frac{\partial}{\partial w_j} \frac{C(uw_1,uw_2)}{u}.$$

I am looking for a rationale behind this. I thought of considering $\dfrac{C(uw_1,uw_2)}{u}$ as a constant sequence of functions in order to apply theorems from analysis but I am unsure about how to proceed.

On the other hand, I am well aware that if $g(j,k)$ is increasing with respect to $j$ and $k$, switching the order of limits is possible as this can be thought of switching the order of summation. But I am unsure if the function I have at hand is increasing with respect to $u$ as $u \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Could you please mention the research paper where you found this?